# accidentally swallowing not-null constraint in Sequelize (probably error-handling in bluebird promises screwup)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js, bluebird

(Note: likely a dumb beginner question),

I'm new to Sequelize and to promises in JS --- and in the course of testing some code that I would expect to throw an error, instead I see a silent failure.

Here's the relevant code (this is using express for a web server, and with a sqllite back-end on disk)

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  "firstName": {type: Sequelize.STRING},
  "lastName": {type: Sequelize.STRING},
  "id": {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},
  "gym": {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false}
});

function addUser(first, last, gym){
  return User.sync().then(() => User.create({"firstName": first, "lastName": last, "gym": gym}))
}

function testBlowUpAdd(req, res){
  addUser(null, null, null).then(res.send("added user")).catch(e => res.send(e.toString()));
}

app.get("/testboom", testBlowUpAdd);
```

When I hit that endpoint, I expect to see whatever error Sequelize throws when you violate a database constraint.  Instead, I see "added user."  However, when I go looking into the database, as expected, my all-null row doesn't appear.

So clearly, I'm accidentally swallowing the error.  Almost certainly because I don't understand how error-handling happens in promises. I would have thought that the call to addUser would throw, and that as a result the promise mechanism wouldn't call the handler in `then()` and would call the handler in `catch()`... but evidently that's incorrect?

Comment: `.catch(e => res.send(e.toString())` isn't accidentally  swallowing the error, it looks quite deliberate ... also `testBlowUpAdd` doesn't return anything, is that by design?

Comment: Are you getting a warning somewhere about headers already being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res.send()` function is being called immediately when the promise is being setup, the return value of `res.send()` is being passed as the argument to `.then()`.

The `.then` argument should be a function, so it can run later when the promise resolves.

```
function testBlowUpAdd(req, res){
  addUser(null, null, null)
    .then(user => res.send("added user"))
    .catch(e => res.send(e.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I was in fact totally misunderstanding the semantics of `then()`. Wheee!